# How to correctly get a per process percent of used CPU using the SIGAR libraries

Tags: c++, cpu-usage, sigar

I'm writing a code to get a per process percent of used CPU, but something is wrong with my code. That displays strange values like 3.63499e+262 % and 0%, while the task manager displays a value bigger than 0% and lower or equal a 100%. What i'm doing wrong?

```
sigar_t *sigarproclist;
sigar_proc_list_t proclist;
sigar_open(&sigarproclist);
sigar_proc_list_get(sigarproclist, &proclist);
for (size_t i = 0; i < proclist.number; i++)
{
    sigar_proc_cpu_t cpu;
    sigar_proc_cpu_get(sigarproclist, proclist.data[i], &cpu);
    sigar_proc_state_t procstate;
    sigar_proc_state_get(sigarproclist, proclist.data[i], &procstate);
    qDebug() << procstate.name << 100 * cpu.percent << "%";
}
sigar_close(sigarproclist);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes in my code, and now it looks valid.

```
sigar_t *sigarcpulist;
sigar_cpu_info_list_t cpulist;
sigar_open(&sigarcpulist);
sigar_cpu_info_list_get(sigarcpulist, &cpulist);
sigar_close(sigarcpulist);

forever
{
    float percent;
    sigar_t *sigarproclist;
    sigar_proc_list_t proclist;
    sigar_open(&sigarproclist);
    sigar_proc_list_get(sigarproclist, &proclist);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < proclist.number; i++)
    {
        sigar_proc_cpu_t cpu;
        sigar_proc_cpu_get(sigarproclist, proclist.data[i], &cpu);
    }
    Sleep(1000);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < proclist.number; i++)
    {
        sigar_proc_cpu_t cpu;
        int status = sigar_proc_cpu_get(sigarproclist, proclist.data[i], &cpu);
        if (status == SIGAR_OK)
        {
            sigar_proc_state_t procstate;
            sigar_proc_state_get(sigarproclist, proclist.data[i], &procstate);
            percent = cpu.percent * 100 / cpulist.size;
            qDebug() << procstate.name << percent << "%";
        }
    }
    sigar_close(sigarproclist);
}
```